# How do I use Jest to test the output in one element, from an input from another element?

Tags: jestjs, svelte

My test is trying to mock a user typing "abcdef" in the textarea as an input, and then verify if the same string ("abcdef") is written in the output:

```
it("should write in input and correspond in output", async () => {
    render(App);

    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'abcdef' }})
    
    let output = document.getElementById("output");
    expect(output).toHaveTextContent("abcdef"); // undefined
});
```

This is the output element:

```
    <h1 id="output">{output}</h1>
```

If I hardcode 'abcdef' next to the {output} tag, then my test passes, but the *fireEvent.change* doesn't seem to work properly. Maybe I misunderstand the capabilities of Jest - maybe it only does unit testing, and not user-tests /end-to-end testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'abcdef' }})
```

should have an `await`:

```
await fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'abcdef' }})
```

And it works!

```
it("should write in input and correspond in output", async () => {
    render(App);
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'abcdef' }})
    let output = document.getElementById("output");
    expect(output).toHaveTextContent("abcdef");
});
```

RESULT:  ✓ should write in input and correspond in output (3 ms)